# Aligning Horizontal UL Menu in DIV

Tags: html, css, centering

Struggling to get my horizontal UL menu to center itself in the parent DIV.

Rather annoying, because it's literally out by about 10-20px.

Any help would be great, thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/xd5cxngt/

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="The-Isle-of-Wight.html">The Isle of Wight</a></li>
            <li><a href="Your Stay">Your Stay</a></li>
            <li><a href="Booking">Booking</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    height: 28px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li a {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line `min-width: 960px;`in your navbar div and it should work.
Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/84etsxzn/

Comment: Thank you very much, however I would still say that even in your version, the whole menu has more space to its left than to its right when in full screen??

Comment: add this to your css: `#menu ul {
    padding-left = 0px;
}`there is a standard 40px padding to you ul

Comment: Sorted, ^^^^^ view my answer above. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was with the User Agent styles.

It was adding 40px as a left-padding.

So used this to remove it, hopefully this should cover most browsers.

`* {-webkit-padding-start: 0px;}`

Thank you Lorenzo for your help though.